# accessing vector iterator elements to output

Tags: c++

I'm pretty new to c++ and I'm trying to create a utility that finds all the network devices and lists their name and MAC address. I've gotten everything to compile, however when I run my `to_string()` method I don't get any output to the terminal. I believe that I am accessing the iterator object and calling `to_string()` on it incorrectly.

```
//networkinterfacelist_class.cpp
#include "networkinterfacelist.h"

//get list of network interfaces and push them into a vector list
networkinterfacelist_class::networkinterfacelist_class(){
  if ((dir = opendir ("/sys/class/net")) != NULL){
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
      std::string device(ent->d_name);

      //skips the parent and current folder
      if(device == "." || device == ".."){
        continue;
      }

      dir_list.push_back(device);
    }
    closedir (dir);
  }
}

//iterate through the devices and find their mac addresses
std::vector<networkinterface_class> networkinterfacelist_class::create_device(){
  for( std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = dir_list.begin(); it != dir_list.end(); ++it){
    if ((dir2 = opendir ("/sys/class/net")) != NULL){
      if ((dir = opendir (it->c_str())) != NULL){

        //opens the address file saves mac address in line
        inFile.open("address");
        while(!inFile){
          getline(inFile, line);
        }

        //creates a new networkinterface class and pushes it onto a list
        networkinterface_class obj( *it , line);
        list.push_back(obj);

      }
    }
  }
  return list;
}

//iterates over the list of network devices and prints their name and mac address
void networkinterfacelist_class::to_string(){
  for(std::vector<networkinterface_class>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it){
    (*it).to_string();
  }
}
```

and my networkinterface class

```
//networkinterface_class.cpp
#include "networkinterface.h"

networkinterface_class::networkinterface_class(std::string device, std::string macaddress){
  name = device;
  mac = macaddress;
}

std::string networkinterface_class::get_name(){
  return name;
}

std::string networkinterface_class::get_mac(){
  return mac;
}

void networkinterface_class::to_string(){
  std::cout << "Name: " << networkinterface_class::get_name() << "\tMAC: " << networkinterface_class::get_mac() << std::endl;
}
```

any help or tips would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked that your list is not empty? Beware that `create_device` returns a copy, so changing the result does not change the `list` member.

Comment: first add a `cout << list.size() << endl;`. I bet your list is empty.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I just checked, the list is empty, any advice on how I can fix it?

Comment: @Jeffrey My only advice would be to attach a debugger and step through the code that generates the list.

Comment: You seem to have some global vectors, or maybe they're data members? Either way I can't see where they're declared, and there's not much point trying to guess. Try reducing your code to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - and that _does_ mean it has to be the smallest complete and self-contained program exhibiting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the whole path for your devices.

```
dir_list.push_back(device); // it pushes only d_name of dirent == filename
```

in above line you push only device name from `/sys/class/net`, so when you want to read this device you need to create the whole path by concatenating */sys/class/net/* with device name

```
if ((dir = opendir ( ("/sys/class/net/" + *it).c_str() )) != NULL){
                                          ^^^ get device name as string
```

instead of

```
if ((dir = opendir (it->c_str())) != NULL){ // you pass only device without full path
```

Do the same when you want to open `address` file:

```
inFile.open("/sys/class/net/" + *it + "/address");
```

now you can read the content of this file.